# Stacked bar chart with multiple facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart with multiple facets using the code below:

```
dat <- read.csv(file="./fig1.csv", header=TRUE)
dat2 <- melt(dat, id.var = "id")
ggplot(dat2, aes(x=id, y=value, fill = variable))  +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
facet_grid(. ~ col1) +
geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

and here is a minimized example of how my data looks like:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1   1   0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1 
2   1   0.2  0.1  0.2  0.1
3   1   0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1
4   2   0.1  0.1  0.2  0.1
5   2   0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
```

However, I keep getting the error below. I think the problem is coming from `facet_grid(. ~ col1)` and more specifically using `col1`.

```
Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, cols, drop = params$drop) : 
At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: The problem is that`col1` is numeric, and your are melting it together with the others. You can set `as.character` columns `id1` and `col1` and then melt them (those two columns will be now variables). you can do: `dat$col1=as.character(dat$col1)`; `dat$id=as.character(dat$id)` ; `dat2 <- melt(dat)`. And then the code you have for the plot

Comment: Or just include `col1` in the melting as variable:`dat2 <- melt(dat, id.var=c("id", "col1"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `col1` is not included as variable in the `melt` function, so it will be melted together with the rest of columns. Just include `col1` as variable in the `melt` function.

```
dat2 <- melt(dat, id.var=c("id", "col1"))
```